# Illustrator script How to generate a cross to center of all selected circles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

Is there a way (or Script) to place a cross (+) at the center of all selected circles?
[image]

Comment: Are all the selected things circles? Or does the process need to identify circles.

Comment: all selected things are circles.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a scatter brush using the **+** object.

Select all the objects, duplicate and ungroup all, open the Transform each panel and give then a 1% size.

Now just apply that **+** brush and group them if you want it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the end results, but you could align the cross in the circle and group them. Then you can spread the group evenly everywhere.

[image: Align Horizontally and Vertically the Cross and the Circle]

1. Align Horizontally and Vertically the Cross and the Circle

[image: Group them together Object > Group or Ctrl + G]

2. Group them together Object > Group or Ctrl + G

[image: Duplicate the group by selecting the group, holding Alt and dragging it somewhere]

3. Duplicate the group by selecting the group, holding Alt and dragging it somewhere

[image: Spread them evenly]

4. Spread them evenly

You could also create a pattern with this group under Object > Pattern > Make

Comment: There should be a capability to show the center point of regular objects automatically.

Comment: @Chris With the Pattern Options window, you have a lot more options.